# "sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 1000, should be 0"

Tags: sudo

Error:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 1000, should be 0<br/>
Segmentation fault.
```

This comes up when trying to mount drives.  USB, external drives , CD are unmountable, so I am unable to access any drives.

Same message comes up with sudo `fdisk -l`:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 1000, should be 0<br/>
Segmentation fault.
```

Output of `desktop:~$ cat /proc/partitions`:

```
major   minor    #blocks name

   8        0  156290904 sda
   8        1  151749958 sda1
   8        2          1 sda2
   8        5    4538331 sda5
   8       16  244198584 sdb
   8       17     102400 sdb1
   8       18  244093952 sdb2
   8       32   15633408 sdc
   8       33   15633392 sdc1
   8       48    7812608 sdd
   8       49    7812592 sdd1
```

Seems to be permission issue that just started. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: i am sorry that i am unable to understand what actually you are asking will you please provide the error messages if any.
or is this your problem http://askubuntu.com/questions/92161/i-am-getting-an-error-while-mounting-my-ntfs-drives

Comment: usb drives used to automount and show up in places.  Now they don't and I am unable to mount them Now just get the segmentation fault message when I try to mount them.  for example , dapper-desktop:~$ sudo su mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 1000, should be 0
Segmentation fault.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changed permissions of / to user](http://askubuntu.com/questions/108702/changed-permissions-of-to-user)

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't set a root password explicitly, I suspect your installation will not be able to be fixed from within.  Boot from an Ubuntu disk, open the volume in Nautilus, then run the following in a Terminal:

```
$ sudo chown root:root /media/*/etc/sudoers
```

I cannot fathom how you would get into this situation in the first place, though.

BTW, your question could use some copy editing, markup, and an actual question.  Hence @VENKI's confusion.