# Can't understand if sudo is working or not

Tags: sudo, reboot, recovery-mode

I don't know what's wrong in my pc. It runs on Ubuntu 16.04.

When I give sudo command, it asks for password. When I give password, it does not accept.

```
sudo -i
[sudo] password for alpha: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for alpha: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for alpha: 
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
alpha@alpha-Inspiron-15-3567:~$
```

The password is correct, I checked that. The keyboard layout is okay, I typed the exact password.

To fix this I tried to follow this: [Cannot run any sudo command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/675898/cannot-run-any-sudo-command)

The Simple fix one did not work, so I tried the complex fix one, rebooting in recovery mode.
Got to this step:

[image: recovery menu]

bit I could not enter the whole command of

```
mount -o remount,rw /
chmod chmod u=rwxs,g=rx,o=rx /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/pkexec
exit
```

before I could complete /usr/bin/sudo, it started to run commands on its own and resumed.
So, here I am, not understanding anything. Can anybody help me ?

Comment: Try `sudo su` and type in the password of your account

Comment: @YoranJansen still not working

Comment: Sorry, buy I don't know then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are executing these commands from a root shell prompt, so you don't need to preface the commands with `sudo` and you don't need to run `sudo -i` at all because you are already root.

The command in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/675898/cannot-run-any-sudo-command/675947#675947) is incorrect because `chmod` is repeated twice:

```
chmod chmod u=rwxs,g=rx,o=rx /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/pkexec
```

The correct command is:

```
chmod u=rwxs,g=rx,o=rx /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/pkexec
```

Comment: so instead of "sudo -i'', I should give only "-i ?

Comment: You don't need to run `sudo -i` at all because you are running the commands from a root shell prompt, so you are already root.

Comment: Another thing I wanna ask, It is asking for password of alpha. and I am giving the password for the user alpha. 
I am using the pc as alpha right ? still when I am using teminal, I am using it as root, while i am logged in as alpha. I cant connect this. I am new to this, so can you explain a little please ?

Comment: Your user that you are currently logged in with can do almost every task, except for tasks that require root privileges like installing or uninstalling software or changing the permissions on files that are not owned by the currently logged in user, such as files that are owned by root. To preform these operations requires prefacing the commands by `sudo` in order to temporarily give the non-root user root privilege to run this command. This is a security measure that protects Ubuntu from unwanted escalation of root privileges, by making it temporary and only enabled in the terminal.

Comment: In my case, I dont require sudo prefix as I am using root shell prompt. How I am able to use root shell (super user) while I am logged in as alpha (simple user) ?

Comment: `/usr/bin/id` will show you what your `UID` and `GID` are in this environment.

Comment: In a normal Ubuntu environment run `sudo -s` to get a root shell and `exit` to exit, but this is not the best way to do it. Instead run `sudo -i` and then you can run commands with root privileges without using `sudo` and then run `exit` to exit back to normal user when you are finished.