# www-data ownership

Tags: server, chown, ownership

I'm very much new to ubuntu. Please help me to change my server settings.

I am trying to install wordpress. Accidentally I ran this command in root directory:

```
sudo chown -R demo:www-data *
```

Now all my directory ownership is changed to www-data. How can I change this back to default setting?

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changed permissions of / to user](http://askubuntu.com/questions/108702/changed-permissions-of-to-user)

Comment: @muru but this is on my server

Comment: @Dee A non-formatting reinstall still works with server installs.

Comment: you have no option than contacting your server admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm. You might have to reinstall your OS :(. But first try switching to root with the command:

```
su
```

Then, from the root directory, run the command to give root ownership to everything:

```
cd /
chown -R root:root *
```

Then go to your user home directory and give ownership back to yourself with:

```
cd /home/username
chown -R username:username *
```

replacing `username` with your real username. Finally switch back to being your normal user:

```
su username
```

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that. A lot of things won't work with this (IDK if you will even be able to log in). Following the directions [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/108702/changed-permissions-of-to-user) (as specified by @muru) can solve your problem.

Comment: @Zzzach... You're probably right, but I'm certainly not going to try it and find out! Nevertheless I still think doing it this way could be worth a shot prior to reinstalling.