# changing ownership of file as group user

Tags: chmod, chown, ownership

let's say i have files owned by:

sftp-user:www-data

now I want that www-data can change the ownership of it, say to foobar. Is that even possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [www-data ownership](http://askubuntu.com/questions/751671/www-data-ownership)

Comment: do you want someone with `groupid www-data` to be able to change the owner of files owned by another user?

Comment: @Yaron yes exactly

Comment: e.g. is it possible if a file owned by sftp-user and group www-data that someone of the group www-data can change the file ownership?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Only the owner of a file or root is permitted to change permissions.**

And even if a file is owned by you, you can't change it ownership to another user. You can however, change its group, to one of the groups which your user is part of.

If a user can execute `sudo` then the user can execute:

```
sudo chown new-owner filename
```

> You can try to manipulate the system files in a way it will be
>   possible, however it will create major security risk to your system.
>
> Such non recommended solution might be:
>
> ```
> sudo cp /bin/chown /bin/chown.mod
> sudo chown root.www-data /bin/chown.mod
> sudo chmod 750 /bin/chown.mod
> sudo chmod +s /bin/chown.mod
> ```
>
> Now, user with groupid www-data can execute `/bin/chown.mod` as user
>   `root`
>
> ```
> /bin/chown.mod userid /path/to/filename
> ```
>
> **It is very dangerous**, for example: as such user can change the owner of /etc/passwd to himself, modify the password file, and change
>   the owner back to root, and  a new user was added to the system.

Comment: Is the rationale for this restriction (in particular, that members of the owning group are not permitted to change permissions) explained anywhere?