# How to grant +x privilege for /?

Tags: command-line, permissions, login, chmod

I executed `sudo chmod -rwx /`

To my surprise, all the icons on the dock vanished and all the commands (from man to `sudo`) are now unrecognised or not found.

The system had only one user.

We shut down the system and tried to login via tty2. The screen runs on a loop.

We are not able to see the normal login screen when We tried boot it up either.

Is there anything that we could do?

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/108702/changed-permissions-of-to-user

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to boot a Live System, mount your system drive and fix it from there.

Step 1: Find an Live medium (USB stick or DVD) you can insert in your system.

Step 2: Boot your system from the Live medium.

Step 3: Open a terminal

Step 4: Find the device name of your damaged root file system (for example using `sudo fdisk -l`), for example `/dev/sda1`.

Step 5: Mount the damaged root file system on `/mnt` with the command

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

Step 6: Fix the damage with the command

```
sudo chmod 755 /mnt
```

Step 7: Unmount the file system again with

```
sudo umount /mnt
```

Step 8: Reboot back into your installation

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more, if you don't mind ?

Comment: Yes it will. `chmod` on a mount point affects the root directory of the filesystem mounted at that point.

Comment: already did that

Comment: Error : Sudo must be owned by Uid 0 and have setuid bit set

Comment: What did you use as Live System? It seems that `sudo`is damaged on that medium.

Comment: Alternatively, become root and use the commands without `sudo` as I wrote originally before Zanna edited them.

Comment: The system on which I performed Chmod has ubuntu 16 . The live medium I used (USB stick) has 14. Will this affect it ..

Comment: No, on both accounts: 1) The `sudo` command of your live medium will not be affected by the system on your hard disk, so the error you reported cannot be caused by the version difference. 2) `mount` and `chmod` are not Ubuntu release specific, so the commands of a working Ubuntu 14 live medium will work fine on your Ubuntu 16 disk.

Comment: How does one become root on a live Ubuntu system without using `sudo -i` or some other variant? There's no root account. You could maybe use recovery mode and start a root shell and remount the filesystem rw instead of using a live boot, idk. @V.AdithyaGanesan Tilman is right, your live system is broken - get a new one (make it on a friend's computer maybe). You should not be getting that error doing it this way.